# Jquery Show/Hide only works on first row of php loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table generated by a php while loop. There is one field that I want to replace when an edit button is clicked (it will contain input fields to update that record).

This works fine for the first row but none of the others work. I assume that after each php loop the jquery has to be cleared but not sure how this is done?

If anyone can see I am missing something obvious, then please let me know!

http://jsfiddle.net/QD564/1/

An example of a couple of the rows

```
<tr>
        <td>2014-06-13</td>
        <td>23:00:00</td>
        <td>WC</td>
        <td>Chile v Australia</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><span id="12942">2 - 0</span><span id="e12942" style="display:none">aa</span>

        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">-</td>
        <td><span id="12942"><button id="showEdit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary 12942" rel="12942">Edit</button></span><span id="e12942" style="display:none"><button id="hideEdit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger 12942" rel="12942">Cancel</button></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2014-06-13</td>
        <td>20:00:00</td>
        <td>WC</td>
        <td>Spain v Holland</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><span id="12941">2 - 2</span><span id="e12941" style="display:none">aa</span>

        </td>
        <td style="text-align:center">-</td>
        <td><span id="12941"><button id="showEdit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary 12941" rel="12941">Edit</button></span><span id="e12941" style="display:none"><button id="hideEdit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger 12941" rel="12941">Cancel</button></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

The script

```
  $("#showEdit").click(function() {
  $("span#e"+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("span#"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("#showEdit."+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("#hideEdit."+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
   return false;
});
$("#hideEdit").click(function() {
  $("span#e"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("span#"+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("#showEdit."+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("#hideEdit"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
   return false;
});
```

Thanks

Steve

Comment: You have a duplicate ID called showEdit, This is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple duplicate id's like in your case, The id selector for jquery will only grab the first id it can find on the dom, which means that if you change the duplicate id and use a class instead, it might work better :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Using classes was the way forward!!!

```
<tr>
<td>2014-06-13</td>
<td>23:00:00</td>  
<td>WC</td>
<td>Chile v Australia</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<span class="12942" style="display: inline;">2 - 0</span>
<span class="e12942" style="display: none;">aa</span></td>
<td style="text-align:center"> - </td>
<td><span id="12942" style="display: inline;"><button id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary showEdit 12942" rel="12942">Edit</button></span><span id="e12942" style="display: none;"><button id="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger hideEdit 12942" rel="12942">Cancel</button></span></td>
```

```
  $(".showEdit").click(function() {
  $("span#e"+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("span#"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("span."+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("span.e"+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
   return false;
});

$(".hideEdit").click(function() {
  $("span#e"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
  $("span#"+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("span."+$(this).attr('rel')).show();
  $("span.e"+$(this).attr('rel')).hide();
   return false;
});
```

Updated the fiddle in case it helps anyone else (if they tidy it up!)

http://jsfiddle.net/QD564/2/

Thanks again for steering me in the right direction!